# Use template engine to parse multi-line log file in Java

Tags: java, parsing, templates, template-engine

I'd like to simplify my log file parser and **replace complex regular expressions with a templates engine**. The idea is to reverse the process of a template engine and give as an input the template description and a valid result file. The multi-line log files look like:

```
*** ID: X821 ***
- type: B5
- time-stamp: 20160202T01:11:01.2991

* Device: XKK-255141
```

All of them have the **same structure** and can be described in a pseudo template language:

```
*** ID: {{string}} ***
- type: {{string}}
- time-stamp: {{date}}

* Device: XKK-{{integer}}
```

Is there a template engine which parses a log file, looks-up the structure in the template file and returns content in a HashMap/List/Object?

**Note:**
I'm aware that I could write a simple DSL in ANTLR. But the idea here is to simplify the parsing and accept that only basic multi-line log files without recursions are supported.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not aware of an existing template engine that does this (they usually work the other way around, filling templates with data).

Why not use something like this:

```
class ReverseTemplateEngine {
   ArrayList<String> prefixes = new ArrayList();
   ArrayList<String> suffixes = new ArrayList();

   public ReverseTemplateEngine(String... templates) {
     for (String s: templates) {
       int cut = s.indexOf("$");
       suffixes.add(s.substring(0, cut));
       prefixes.add(s.substring(cut + 1);
     }
   }

   public List<String> parse(BufferedReader r) {
     ArrayList<String> result = new ArrayList<>();
     while (true) {
       String line = reader.readLine();
       for (int i = 0; i < prefixes.length; i++) {
         if (line.startsWith(prefixes.get(i)) 
             && line.endsWith(suffixes.get(i)) {
           result.add(line.substring(prefixes.get(i).length(),
                      line.length() - suffixes.get(i).length()));
           break;
         }
       }
     }
     return list;
   }
 }
```

Usage:

```
ReverseTemplateEngine rte = new ReverseTemplateEngine(
   "*** ID: $ ***",
   "- type: $",
   "- time-stamp: $",
   "* Device: XKK-$");

List<String> result = rte.parse(new BufferedReader(
     new FileReader("yourfile.txt")));
```

Comment: Stefan, thanks for sharing the code! This is a pretty smart way to solve the problem.

Answer (score 1):

How about a "simple" Multi-Line Regex?

```
String test = 
  "*** ID: X821 ***\n" + 
  "- type: B5\n" + 
  "- time-stamp: 20160202T01:11:01.2991";

java.util.regex.Pattern p = java.util.regex.Pattern.compile(
  "^\\*\\*\\* ID: (\\S+) \\*\\*\\*\\s+" + 
  "- type: (\\S+)\\s+" + 
  "- time-stamp: (\\S+)", 
  java.util.regex.Pattern.MULTILINE);

java.util.regex.Matcher m = p.matcher(test);
if(m.find()) {
    System.out.println("ID = " + m.group(1));
    System.out.println("type = " + m.group(2));
    System.out.println("time = " + m.group(3));
}
```

It's a bit messy to write because of the backslash and wildcard escapes, but it does the trick... (and on top of this logic you could easily write a string transformation which would map your template matching string to a regex, if you want to).

Answer (score -1):

There are plenty of them.

Check out [YAML](http://yaml.org/) and [JSON](http://www.json.org/). They are really easy to use.

The only problem is, you have to follow the format of each template language.

Here is how your file would be written in these languages.

YAML

```
-- YAML
ID : X821
type : B5
time-stamp : 2016-02-02 01:11:01.2991
Device :
 - XKK : 255141
```

JSON

```
{
    "__comment" : "JSON",
    "ID": "X821",
    "type": "B5",
    "time-stamp": 20160202T01:11:01.2991,
    "Device": {
        "XKK": 255141
    }
}
```

Comment: I want to parse the input files and not changing the format of them.